# How do I convert razor syntax to string usable by jquery?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have this string. I am creating this dropdown so that I can produce them on a callback. This just refuses to come out properly. What am I doing wrong? The error is saying that I am not handling the razor part properly.

```
   var dropdown = '@Html.DropDownList("Table", new SelectList(Enum.GetValues(typeof(GunneryTracker.Models.Table))), "--Table--", new { @class = "form-control3" })';
```

Comment: Your descriptions of the problem all need to be more specific.

Comment: "The error is saying that I am not handling the razor part properly."  No error says that.  What does it *actually* say?

Comment: Looks like you are trying to create a block of code on the client side. Razor is server side generated so returning it on a AJAX call wouldn't work out to well. What are you trying to achieve? That might be easier to handle.

Comment: it says "Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token". specifically, I am trying to create this dropdown in a variable so that I can have a dynamic number of them once it is created on the client side. I am creating this to put in a function so that when a user presses a + sign, it will put another dropdown on the screen. I have it working with a hard coded drop down. I just want my data to come from the db.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not shure if I understood what you mean but sometimes the problem is about mix javascript and server code. If you're trying to attrib the Html.Dropdownlist's processed result to a javascript variable, try to use the '' tags around your variable declaration.

```
<script>
@{
<text>var myVar = '@Html.TextBox("textbox name")';</text>
}</script>
```

This is justa an example since the code below also works, is cleaner and produces the same result.

```
<script>
var myVar = '@Html.TextBox("textboxname")';</script>
```

Both results in:

```
<script>
var myVar = '<input id="textboxname" name="textboxname" type="text" value="" />';</script>
```